# How to return two different View inside onCreateView method of fragment depending on results of asyn background call to server in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i have a fragment in which we have to return  the view depending on result of Background thread. but currently i get null pointer Exception.

this is our Fragment class:

```
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {

String ss = null;
GridView gridView;
ArrayList<ProductParameterBO> productlist;
GridViewCustomAdapter gridViewCustomAdapter;
ArrayList<View> viewList;
public int itemSelected = 0;
private static boolean isFirstTime = false;
RequestObject requestObject;
JSONObject jsonObject1;


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String responseString = "{\"rqBody\" :" + "{"+ "}}" ;
    try {
        requestObject = new RequestObject();
        requestObject.setJsonSend(responseString);
        requestObject.setUrl(NetworkUrl.GETPRODUCTINFO_URL);

        new GetProductInfo().execute(requestObject);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {




    if (jsonObject1.length()==0){
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_catalog_item,null);

        TextView configure = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_conf);

        configure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SplitViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("firstTab","1stTabs");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        TextView text_here = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_here);
        text_here.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditUploadActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

      return rootView;
    }else {

        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product,null);

        gridView =(GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        viewList = new ArrayList<View>();

        productlist = new ArrayList<ProductParameterBO>();

        productlist.add(new ProductParameterBO("Type","Numeric","yes","yes"));
        productlist.add(new ProductParameterBO("Typess","Numericss","yesss","yesss"));
        productlist.add(new ProductParameterBO("Typess","Numericss","yesss","yesss"));
        productlist.add(new ProductParameterBO("Typess","Numericss","yesss","yesss"));
        gridViewCustomAdapter = new GridViewCustomAdapter(getActivity(),productlist);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewCustomAdapter);
        gridViewCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {

                if (isFirstTime) {
                    viewList.get(itemSelected).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d("Inside", "Selected");
                }

                RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_img_ovrly);
                viewList.add(relativeLayout);
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemSelected = position;
                isFirstTime = true;

                Log.d("outside", "Selected");

            }
        });


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditUploadActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }

   // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product,null);
}


private class GetProductInfo extends AsyncTask<RequestObject, Void, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context;


    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(RequestObject... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceCallHandler sh = new ServiceCallHandler();
        // RequestObject requestObject = new RequestObject();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(arg0[0], ServiceCallHandler.POST);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        String status=null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                jsonObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rsBody");
               /* if (jsonObject.has("name")){
                    status = jsonObject.getString("status");

                }*/


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject1 = result;



    }

}
```

}

i want that depending on **JsonObject1** we return view inside oncreate method,but we get nullpointer exception. i think oncreate method called before background thread.How can i call my server call first and depending on their results we show the view.

Any help would be appreciated in advance....

Comment: Set your fragment view in onPostExecute() method of asyncTask.

Comment: thanks Saritha, but can you explain through code... i didn't get

Comment: where did u call your AsyncTask inside activity or Fragment??

Comment: In your postExecute() method replace your code with this `jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(result);`

Comment: you call api in  one fragment view after you got result. based on result you want to show different fragment view in existing one write.

Comment: Why don't you call asyncTask in Activity.?

Comment: and when you have already parsed your response in doInBackground() why you are doing it again in postExecute() ??

Comment: no we have to use fragment

Comment: can i write onCreateView() inside postExecute() method?

Comment: no..When you attached fragment to activity. then onCreateView method will be called, and onCreateView() runs on mainThread there is no link with the AsyncTask.

Comment: i call AsyncTask inside fragment, is there any way to call asyncTask first before oncreateView()?

Comment: Call it in activity and then pass the result of AsyncTask to fragment. based on result you have to return the view.

Comment: ok i try then back to you..thanks

Answer (score 1):

First Display the empty view in your onCreateView() method. In onPostExecute() method you will get the response, based no that response, inflate the view from xml file and add the inflated view to empty view which is returned in onCreateView().

Something like below:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        if (result == null || result.length() == 0) {
            RelativeLayout one = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
             //Here getView() is empty view which is returned in onCreateView
            if (getView() != null) {
                ((LinearLayout) getView()).addView(one);
            }
        } else {
            LinearLayout one = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_login_facebook, null);
            if (getView() != null) {
                ((LinearLayout) getView()).addView(one);
            }
        }
    }
```

(OR)

Call the asyncTask in Activity, send the response to fragment depends on condition retrun the view in onCreateView().

Comment: thanks Saritha, i call asyncTask in activity and pass the results in fragment ,it solve my query

Comment: glad to help u..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_notification_fragment,container,false); //first layout

    View view1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_offline,container,false);             //second layout   

    //On back press for view....

    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view.requestFocus();
    view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("home");
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    //On back press for view1....

    view1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    view1.requestFocus();
    view1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("home");
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });


    /* Depending on the condition....returning the views...*/
    if(notificationsList.size() == 0){
        return view1;
    }else{
        return view;
    }

}
```